# Deserializing response

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, restsharp

I'm using RestRequest to make a POST to web service. Response is in JSON format, but I get it in response.Content as ASCII, and Data is null. code is:

```
        var request = new RestRequest(api, Method.POST);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddObject(data);

        RestClient client = new RestClient("http://IP:PORT/proto");           
        client.ExecuteAsync<jLoginResponse>(request, (response) =>
        {
            var resource = response.Data;
        });
```

and here response.Data is empty, and Content is 
    {"uid":"1234"}

jLoginResponse is declared as

```
[DataContract]
public class jLoginResponse
{
    public string uid { get; set; }
}
```

but it's not getting deserialized automatically as it should.

Answer (score 1):

The class should have the members marked with `DataMember`, like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class jLoginResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public string uid { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: no it shouldn't, RestSharp doesn't use this placeholders. Problem was that server was posting json as text, not application/json.

Comment: RestSharp uses JSON.net for JSON serialization, and JSON.net can use attributes (placeholders) if you set it to "Explict Serialization", it even has it's own JsonProperty, per example... but I'm glad the problem is solved!

Comment: So if I set it to explicit I could use [DataMember Name="..."] and it would evaluate it properly?

Comment: Exactly @Marin, please check here for more info: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/SerializationAttributes.html

Comment: If you're reading this today, the latest version of RestSharp doesn't use JSON.net. Instead it uses a built-in serializer which cannot read DataMember decorators.